# Deny certain URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently using Scrapy for my project on university institutional repository where I need to get the external link for each university. Is there a way for me to deny certain URLs such as 'google.com' and 'twitter.com'. Below is what I have at the moment. I'm new to these so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
 import scrapy 

    class UtmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'utm'
        start_urls = ['http://eprints.utm.my/id/eprint/']


        def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.Request('http://eprints.utm.my/id/eprint/', self.parse)

        def parse(self, response):
            for href in response.xpath('//a/@href').getall():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), self.parse)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add a conditional like e.g. `if 'google' not in href: yield blah`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ignore = ['google', 'twitter']
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//a/@href').getall():
        for kw in ignore:
            if kw not in href.lower():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), self.parse)
```

As per request

EDIT:

You asked how you could exclude certain links that contain text like the examples you gave, Google and Twitter.

I have not changed what your code does, but simply added a conditional statement which will check if the href contains the keywords.

We create a list (our list of excluded terms). Then we will need to iterate that list each time we want to check a link, so the shorter the list of keywords the better.

If the keyword value is not part of the href string, we pass and continue the href link iteration. Otherwise we yield it instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for helping me out with this! And if I want to include some specific domain, I can still use this right?

Comment: All domains are included in my answer, unless you add the domain to the `ignore` list. It will not effect crawling other sites, but be certain that `google` isn't part of one the hrefs in the iteration, and I say this because if the href is the entire url, then if there was a link e.g. www.mydomain.com/google/api_hook then this url would also be ignored . And if this is the case, I would suggest changing your keywords like so `ignore = ['.google.', '.twitter.']` as this will explicitly match the domain section more accurately. You didn't say it was the domain, just text in a link

Answer (score 0):

If your spider is simple then solution from Swift will work just fine.
If your spider/spiders have quite a lot of code in them checking urls every time you want to issue a request will pollute your code. In this case you can use DownloaderMiddleware pipeline.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
If you search for 'IgnoreRequest' you'll find a description of how to implement a DownloaderMiddleware that will be able to discard certain requests.